# visual studio 2015 debugging xsl transformation failed SecurityException

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging xsl in vs 2015 why am I getting the following error

```
﻿SecurityException
-----------------
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

XSL generated a security exception. If you trust this stylesheet then copying it to your local hard drive will remove this security check. But it is highly advised that you review all script blocks and HTTP requests in the stylesheet before you do so.

FirstPermissionThatFailed

You can enable automatic downloads on the Miscellaneous XML Options page under the Text Editor category of the Tools/Options dialog.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a couple of things and this error went away.

First, I exited VS and reopened by right clicking the startup icon, clicking 'more'->'run as administrator'

That alone might have been sufficient to fix the issue, but I also did as the error message above suggested and went to the VS menu and clicked

tools->options->text editor->xml->miscellaneous

under 'network' there is a checkmark in 'Automatically download dtds and schemas' so I would think I would be OK as I want to download a document (not an xsd or dtd, but an xml via the xsl document function) but, since it didn't work when the box was checked, I unchecked (cleared) the box.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution and experiences here, nice answer. You can mark it. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

my earlieir answer works, sometimes.  the root cause however is that visual studio, if you open your project as a web site solution, gives no permissions to the document function to fetch documents.  If you open your xsl files in folder mode you'll have max security permissions except for https fetches.